# Rules of distribution of quantifiers over conditional and biconditional

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, first-order-logic, quantifiers

Which of the following propositional logic statements are true and why?

1. $(∀x(P(x)⟹Q(x)))⟹((∀xP(x))⟹(∀xQ(x)))$
2. $(∀x(P(x))⟹∀x(Q(x)))⟹(∀x(P(x)⟹Q(x)))$
3. $(∀x(P(x))⇔(∀x(Q(x))))⟹(∀x(P(x)⇔Q(x)))$
4. $(∀x(P(x)⇔Q(x)))⟹(∀x(P(x))⇔(∀x(Q(x))))$
5. Are their any standard laws/rules of distribution of universal quantifier over conditional and binconditional that can help me solve this?
6. Also rules for distribution of existential quantifier over conditional and binconditional?

Recently I came across distribution of quantifiers over $\vee$ and $\wedge$, which gave set theoretic interpretation of them as follows:

- $((∀x)G(x)∨ (∀x)H(x))→ (∀x)(F(x)∨ G(x))$

  In set theoretic terms,
  if we have that $(f(G) = D ∨ f(H) = D)$, then we have $(f(G) ∪ f(H)) = D$
- $(∃x)(G(x)∧ H(x))→((∃x)G(x)∧ (∃x)H(x))$

  In set theoretic terms,
  if we have that $(f(G) ∩ f(H)) ≥ 1$, then we have $(f(G) ≥ 1 ∧ f(H) ≥ 1)$

Can we say similar for distribution of quantifiers over conditional and biconditional (just to bring in more clarity)?

Comment: The above formulas are not propositional, since they use quantifiers. They are just formulas of first-order logic.

Comment: Do you want me to change the title to something else?

Comment: Yes, the title is misleading, as well as the tag "propositional calculus".

Comment: Does the new one makes sense "Rules of distribution of quantifiers over conditional and biconditional makes sense?"

Comment: Now the title is ok for me.

Answer (score 1):

Formulas (1) and (4) are valid, i.e. they are true in every first-order $\mathcal{L}$-structure.

Formulas (2) and (3) are not valid, i.e. there exists a $\mathcal{L}$-structure in which they are not true. For instance, take the $\mathcal{L}$-structure $\mathcal{N}$ whose domain is $\mathbb{N}$ and whose interpretation of $P$ is $2\mathbb{N}$ (the set of even natural numbers), and whose interpretation of $Q$ is $\mathbb{N} \smallsetminus 2\mathbb{N}$ (the set of odd natural numbers). You have that the formula $\forall xP(x) \Rightarrow \forall x Q(x)$ is vacuously true in $\mathcal{N}$ (it claims that "if every natural number is even then every natural number is odd"), but the formula $\forall x(P(x) \Rightarrow Q(x))$ is false in $\mathcal{N}$ (it claims that "for every natural number, if it is even then it is odd"), therefore your formula (2) is false in $\mathcal{N}$. Similarly for the formula (3), since $A \Leftrightarrow B$ is equivalent to $(A \Rightarrow B) \land (B \Rightarrow A)$.

In general, when one talks about distributivity of something over something else (for instance, distributivity of  $\land$ over $\lor$), one means that two formulas are *logically equivalent*. With this meaning, the answer to your question "Does the universal quantifier distribute over conditional or biconditional?" is negative since the formula $\forall xP(x) \Rightarrow \forall x Q(x)$ is not logically equivalent to the formula $\forall x(P(x) \Rightarrow Q(x))$ (your formula (1) is valid, but your formula (2) is not valid), and similarly the formula $\forall xP(x) \Leftrightarrow \forall x Q(x)$ is not logically equivalent to formula $\forall x(P(x) \Leftrightarrow Q(x))$ (your formula (4) is valid, but your formula (3) is not valid).

Comment: Well I have not taken a dedicated course on mathematical strucutres or read any books specifically on mathematical structures. So I am finding it difficult to deal with **$L$-structure** thingy...

Comment: ...However,if interprete $P(x)$ as "x is a boy" & "$Q(x)$ is clever". Then, $(∀x(P(x)⇔Q(x)))$ means "*If any $x$ is a boy then he is clever & vice versa*". This definitely implies $(∀x(P(x))⇔(∀x(Q(x))))$, "If all $x$ are boys then all are clever & vice versa". But converse does not seem valid as $(∀x(P(x))⇔(∀x(Q(x))))$ puts restriction: "if all $x$ are boys". $(∀x(P(x)⇔Q(x)))$ requires that "for any $x$, if $x$ is a boy", but does not require that "all $x$ are boys", so there may be a person who is not boy, but still $(∀x(P(x)⇔Q(x)))$ will be valid but $(∀x(P(x))⇔(∀x(Q(x))))$ will not be...

Comment: ...So 3 seems invalid to me, while 4 seems valid. Also what about distributing existential quantifier?

Comment: @PardonMeForMySuperPoorMaths: Sorry, there was a typo in my answer, now I fixed it. Your formula (4) is the "biconditional version" of your formula (1), and your formula (3) is the "biconditional version" of your formula (2).

Comment: any comment about the same but involving existential quantifier?

Comment: I gave bit more thoughts & now I feel both 3 and 4 are valid. That is $(∀x(P(x))⇔∀x(Q(x)))⇔(∀x(P(x)⇔Q(x)))$. I guess my mistake was to say (in comments above): “there may be a person  who is not boy, but still $(∀x(P(x)⇔Q(x)))$ will be valid but $(∀x(P(x))⇔(∀x(Q(x))))$ will not be”. However $⇔$ is not true only when both sides are true, it is also true when both sides are false: $p↔q≡(p∧q)∨(¬p∧¬q)$. So I thought this:[image](http://bit.ly/1P8sz4M) & ended up concluding both 3 and 4 are valid. Am I correct?

Comment: ....or I was correct earlier and incorrect in above comment? And this:[image](http://s8.postimg.org/ijc7mz9h1/Untitled2.png) is how it should be? Again making 3 invalid and 4 valid? ohhh this logic always confuses me. :'^(

Comment: @PardonMeForMySuperPoorMaths: the fact that in some cases (i.e. for some $\mathcal{L}$-structures, for instance your universe containing only two persons) the formulas $\forall x(P(x) \Leftrightarrow Q(x))$ and $\forall x P(x) \Leftrightarrow \forall x Q(x)$ have the same truth value does not imply that the two formulas are logically equivalent (i.e. have the same truth value in all cases).