# Why does the distribution of quantifiers not work the other way round?

Tags: logic

What are the mathematical examples that the distribution of quantifiers  over implication / equivalence does not work the other way round?

(∀xφ(x)⇒∀xψ(x)) ⇒ (∀x(φ(x) ⇒ ψ(x))

(∃xφ(x)⇒∃x ψ(x)) ⇒ (∀x(φ(x)⇒ψ(x))

(∀x φ(x)⇔∀ x ψ(x))⇒ (∀x(φ(x)⇔ψ(x))

(∃xφ(x)⇔∃xψ(x))⇒(∀x(φ(x)⇔ψ(x))

---

As in this example:
∀x(φ(x)∨ψ(x) ⇒(∀xφ(x)∨∀xψ(x))

does not work in this case:

Let domain = Z

Let P(x) = x is even

Let Q(x) = x is odd

Then: tval(LHS) = T, but tval(RHS) = F

Comment: See the similar [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1596451/rules-of-distribution-of-quantifiers-over-conditional-and-biconditional).

Answer (score 1):

I'll do the first one ... hopefully it'll inspire you to do the others yourself ...

Domain: Z

$\varphi(x)$: $x$ is even

$\psi(x)$: $x$ is odd

Then $\forall x \varphi(x)$ is false, and hence $\forall x \varphi(x) \rightarrow \forall x \psi(x)$ is true

But  $\forall x (\varphi(x) \rightarrow \psi(x))$ is false: it is false that every even integer is odd.